# why is python running at over 90 percent on cpu all the time in ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: configuration, python, process

I just checked my processes over last 3 hours and python was running over 90 percent,sometimes 110.whats causing this ?it says something about a checkbox running when i hover over it.I uninstalled two apps-onboard keyboard and system testing and it seems that python is eased off and not even listed in processes.Is this a bug or can anyone tell me what python does exactly?whats a checkbox?I think the last thing I tried to do before this happened was run system testing and testing halted.When I closed it out then reopened it had a box open saying another checkbox was running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is an "interpreter", similar to Java for instance. It runs applications. Any application that's written in the Python programming language will be run by a python process. This means that saying "python is running 90%" doesn't really tell us much. It simply means "some application is running".

In this case, however, you provided a hint. Checkbox is the actual Python program that is running. It is a system to test different types of software. It is used for System Testing, which is used to test hardware support, among other things.

Uninstalling an application doesn't exit the application (otherwise, upgrading the system while it is running would be impossible), so even if you have uninstalled system testing, it will still be running. It is difficult to know exactly why it doesn't quit. There's too many unknowns. However, if you log out and back in, the problem will go away. Or if you had to enter your password when running the test (running it as the 'root' user), a reboot will exit that application if it doesn't stop.

Otherwise, you can open System Monitor and find the Python process running the "checkbox" instance. Then you can right-click and kill it.

Comment: I did perform a reboot and noticed python was still pegging over 90 percent when I logged back in.The only thing in this instance that put python to sleep was to uninstall system testing.After uninstalling everything was fine.When i started testing I noticed system testing froze so I closed it.Upon reopening it I saw the popup about checkbox running.I also noticed elsewhere that when I opened firefox and closed it the page I had been looking at was still in the titlebar until I clicked desktop then it would say desktop.When uninstalling system testing I feel i killed two birds here

Comment: I removed the lagging of titles staying in top bar and rested python.Now removing system testing-what problems can it cause as far as systemwise in the future?I seriously dont think I need it if it doesnt run as supposed to

Comment: Python is not an application. It's like Java. There are thousands of different applications that runs Python and they will all look similar if you only look at the command.You have to look at what is being run, not the interpreter.

Comment: thank you for your answers here jo-erlend.I understand what your saying now and it is very helpful info

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)